# Can a piece of metal with a specified shape resonate at a certain frequency?

Tags: antenna

I asked this question because I've read that antennas resonate at a certain frequency depending on its length. However, they are connected to some wire or coaxial cable, which I thought might be the reason why they are able to resonate.
What I am asking is whether we can say the same (it resonates) for a piece of metal rod with a specific length, but unconnected to any cable or wire whatsoever, If they intercept electromagnetic waves?

Comment: What's the difference between a wire and a rod?

Comment: I mean only the antenna part without cable

Comment: Is a piece of copper 1.8 cm long a rod or a wire or an antenna?  https://www.wired.com/2013/08/project-west-ford/

Comment: idk, I thought maybe the cable has some resistance or something.. I also thought the rod as a perfect conductor but I might be wrong..

Comment: Please learn about *Yagi-Uda antennas*. They are very simple and have directional and reflector elements which are connected to nothing. Yet they influence the directional characteristic of the main dipole.

Comment: Since you're posting here, I assume you don't mean a mechanical resonance? A tuning fork is a well-known example of mechanical resonance. And the two can be coupled - an electro-magnetic field can cause mechanical movement. That's how a loudspeaker works.

Comment: No I don't mean mechanical resonance.

Comment: Yes, see how it was used during WW2:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaff_(countermeasure)

Comment: The energy reflected depends on wavelength and orientation and thus aperture size relative to 1/2 wavelength of emitter.

Answer (score 1):

### Indeed, an unconnected piece of wire will have a self-resonant frequency

What you are describing is basically identical to an parasitic element on a Yagi-Uda (or just Yagi for short, or often "beam" for the pattern it puts out) antenna.  Whether it be a reflector (longer than half-wave) or director (shorter than half-wave), its pickup of the radiated wave from the driven element allows it to reradiate that EM wave, and the fact it is shorted at the middle creates a phase shift, causing the pattern to change.